# Nest JS: httpService get request not firing when called

Tags: typescript, axios, nestjs

When calling the function `getGeoCoding()` the function starts and prints the message
`"geo coding"` to the console so I know the function is running. However `this.httpService.get` does not fire and returns nothing, not even an error. I have tried to write this function as many different ways as possible however nothing works. I'm trying to access the mapbox api. I know that my api key and search query are fine as I have tested the api in a JavaScript Node app and this returns the correct repsonse from the mapbox api. How can I get the get request to fire in Nest Js using the HttpModule and HttpService from the @nestjs/axios package? Thanks in advance.

Nest Js

```
@Injectable()
export class GeoCodingService {

    constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpService) {}

        async getGeoCoding(): Promise<any[]> {

        console.log("geo coding")

            const { data } = await firstValueFrom(

              this.httpService.get<any[]>(url).pipe(

                catchError((error: AxiosError) => {

                  console.log(error.response.data)

                  throw 'An error happened!';

                }),

              ),

            );
        
            return data;

          }
 
};
```

JavaScript

```
const axios = require("axios");

const geoLocationSearch = async () => {

    try {
      let response = await axios.get(url);
      let to_return = await response.data;
      console.log(to_return);
  }
  catch(err) {
      console.log("Err")
  }
    
}

geoLocationSearch();
```

Comment: if you just want to use axios withtout rxjs, you could use the [`nestjs-http-promise`](https://npmjs.com/nestjs-http-promise) instead. Or use `axios` directly like you did already.

Comment: All sorted, thank you so much!